# Why does java.awt.Font.getStringBounds give different result on different machines?

Tags: java, fonts, awt

I have an application that generates PDF reports (using JasperReports), however if I run my application on my development laptop the text fields have a slightly different size than when I generate the exact same report on the server. I eventually reduced the issue to the following code:

```java
final Font font = Font.createFont(
    Font.TRUETYPE_FONT,
    MyTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/fonts/europa/Europa-Bold.otf")
).deriveFont(10f);
System.out.println(font);
System.out.println(font.getStringBounds(
    "Text",
    0,
    4,
    new FontRenderContext(null, true, true)
));
```

On my Laptop this prints:

```
java.awt.Font[family=Europa-Bold,name=Europa-Bold,style=plain,size=10]
java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Float[x=0.0,y=-9.90999,w=20.080002,h=12.669988]
```

On the server this prints:

```
java.awt.Font[family=Europa-Bold,name=Europa-Bold,style=plain,size=10]
java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Float[x=0.0,y=-7.6757812,w=20.06897,h=10.094452]
```

As you can see I actually ship the font file with the application, so I believe that there is no chance that both machines actually work with a different font.

I would have guessed that under these conditions the output of `getStringBounds` is system-independent. Obviously it is not. What could possibly cause the difference?

Comment: @AndrewThompson: As written in the first sentence of the question I generate PDF reports. The different sizes cause the text to align slightly differently. It is just a few pixels, however if there is text close to a border, than that may already look rather awkward.

Comment: Missed that. My bad. Do you get a consistent result from the `GlyphVector`? `public static Shape getShapeOfText(Font font, String msg) {
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();

FontRenderContext frc = g.getFontRenderContext();
GlyphVector gv = font.createGlyphVector(frc, msg);

return gv.getOutline();
}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Disclaimer! : I'm not a font dev expert, just sharing my experience.*

Yes, it's kind of native. Even new JavaFX web view for example, is depends on `webkit`.

If you dive into debugging for `getStringBounds`, you will realize it reaches a point, where font manager should decide to load a concreted font manager, where the class name is supposed to be system property `sun.font.fontmanager`.

Source code of `sun.font.FontManagerFactory`

```
...
private static final String DEFAULT_CLASS;
    static {
        if (FontUtilities.isWindows) {
            DEFAULT_CLASS = "sun.awt.Win32FontManager";
        } else if (FontUtilities.isMacOSX) {
            DEFAULT_CLASS = "sun.font.CFontManager";
            } else {
            DEFAULT_CLASS = "sun.awt.X11FontManager";
            }
    }
...
public static synchronized FontManager getInstance() {
...
String fmClassName = System.getProperty("sun.font.fontmanager", DEFAULT_CLASS);
}
```

Those `DEFAULT_CLASS` values could validate your *Obviously it is not. What could possibly cause the difference?* mark.

The val for `sun.font.fontmanager` may be `sun.awt.X11FontManager` for some nix systems, but could be `null` for windows for instance, so the manager will be `sun.awt.Win32FontManager`.

Now each manager, may depends on vary underlying shaping/rendering engine/impl for sure([this may help](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_text_layout)).

Main reason could be the nature of fonts. As they are mostly vector stuffs. So based on platform/env, a rendered text could be bigger, or smaller. e.g., maybe windows apply desktop cleartype, and screen text size(DPI) on requested text rendering.

It seems, even if you have exactly two `sun.awt.X11FontManager` manager, the results will be vary. [this may help too](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/awt001.html)

If you just try out the sample code, on online compilers, you will face with vary results for sure.

Result of ideaone (https://ideone.com/AuQvMV), could not be happened, `stderr` has some interesting info

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/jdk/lib/libfontmanager.so: libfreetype.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(ClassLoader.java:2430)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2487)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:2684)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2638)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:827)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1902)
    at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerNativeLibrary$1.run(FontManagerNativeLibrary.java:57)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:310)
    at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerNativeLibrary.<clinit>(FontManagerNativeLibrary.java:32)
    at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager$1.run(SunFontManager.java:270)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:310)
    at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager.<clinit>(SunFontManager.java:266)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:415)
    at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(FontManagerFactory.java:82)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:310)
    at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory.getInstance(FontManagerFactory.java:74)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.getFont2D(Font.java:497)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.getFamily(Font.java:1410)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.getFamily_NoClientCode(Font.java:1384)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.getFamily(Font.java:1376)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.toString(Font.java:1869)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:3042)
    at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:897)
    at Ideone.main(Main.java:19)
```

Note the failed/missed load of `libfreetype` which is a native/`C` font rendering app

Result of coding ground (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php)

```
fnt manager: sun.awt.X11FontManager
java.awt.Font[family=Dialog,name=tahoma,style=plain,size=10]
java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Float[x=0.0,y=-9.282227,w=22.09961,h=11.640625]
```

Result of jdoodle (https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler/)

```
fnt manager: sun.awt.X11FontManager
java.awt.Font[family=Dialog,name=tahoma,style=plain,size=10]
java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Float[x=0.0,y=-9.839991,w=24.0,h=12.569988]
```

My machine

```
fnt manager: null
java.awt.Font[family=Tahoma,name=tahoma,style=plain,size=10]
java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Float[x=0.0,y=-10.004883,w=19.399414,h=12.0703125]
```

**My Story** *(may help, you may try)*

I had similar issue back in some years ago, where text rendering using exactly same embedded font failed on `macOs/jdk8`, for complex text rendering(lots of ligatures). Not just sizes, but also broken ligatures, kerning, etc...

I could fix my issue(cannot remember if fixed the sizing, but no broken ligatures for sure), using another workground, as following

```
InputStream is = Main.class.getResourceAsStream(fontFile);
Font newFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().registerFont(newFont);
//later load the font by constructing a Font ins
Font f = new Font(name/*name of the embedded font*/, style, size);
```

Registering font using `GraphicsEnvironment`, and then instancing it using `Font` fixed our issue. So you may also give it a try.

**Solution**

Finally, I just step-down the jdk stuffs(it's really great pain in neck) for good, and came up with `harfbuzz`(shaping) + `freetype`(rendering) native impl that indeed was a peace in mind.

So...

• You may consider your production server(easy way) as reference for rendered font advance and rendering, and validate the result based on it(rather than dev machine)
• Or, use a cross and standalone (and probably native) shaping/rendering font engine/impl to make sure dev and production results will be the same.